# Could someone explain to me how $x$ and $y$ are computed for this curve?

Tags: calculus

Question: compute the work done by the force field $F$ along the curve $C$.

$F(x,y) = (2x, 2y)$. $C$ is the line segment from $(3,1)$ to $(5,4)$.

Answer given in textbook: $x = 3 + 2t$ and $y = 1 + 3t$. Using these equations the answer comes to $31$.

Could someone explain to me why $x = 3 + 2t$ and $y = 1 + 3t$? That is where I am confused.

Thank you.

Comment: That is a parameterization of the line from $(3.1)$, at $t=0$, to $(5,4)$, at $t=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The $x=3+2t$ and $y=1+3t$ for $t$ ranging from $0$ to $1$ come from a parametrization of the line segment along which you are taking the line integral.

Using this parametrization to compute we get
$$
\int F\cdot dl=\int_0^1F((x(t),y(t))\cdot (dx(t),dy(t)) dt=\int_0^1(6+4t)2+(2+6t)3dt\\=12t+4t^2+6t+9t^2\vert_0^1=12+4+6+9=31
$$

Answer (score 0):

The parametrization of a segment is

$$(x,y)=a(1-t) + bt, \ \ \ 0 \leq t \leq 1$$

In such way when $t=0$ you start in $a$ and when $t=1$ you finish in $b$

With $a=(3,1)$ and $b=(5,4)$

$$(x,y)=(3,1)(1-t)+(5,4)t=(2t+3,3t+1)$$